# How to open a path in python in windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I'd like to open a file in  Windows 10, but open() always fails, even when trying to use PureWindowsPath, pathlib.Path and os.path.join

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'D:\\programmieren\\python\\pixie\\pixie\\data\\tokens\\databasecred.json'
```

I have a constant DATAPATH which contains the string "./data/", after that I add 'tokens/databasecred.json' to create a file variable.

I just want to open it with the function open(), but it fails due to escaping, seemingly added by said function. And I tried everything to make it work in Windows.

```py
from pixie import data
file = data.DATAPATH + 'tokens/databasecred.json'

"""Examples won't work because I always get the error with wrong path said above"""

file = os.path.relpath(file)
f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

f = open(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), os.path.basename(file))))

f = open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), os.path.basename(file))))

file = Path(file) 
f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

file = PureWindowsPath(file)
f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Here's the output of the console

```
    print(data.DATAPATH)
    >>>./data/

    file = data.DATAPATH + 'tokens/databasecred.json'
    file = os.path.relpath(file)

    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:                     
    'data\\tokens\\databasecred.json'

    f = open(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file),     
    os.path.basename(file))))
    >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:         
    'data\\tokens\\databasecred.json'

    f = open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file),         
    os.path.basename(file))))
    >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:     
    'D:\\programmieren\\python\\pixie\\pixie\\data\\tokens\\databasecred.json'

    file = Path(file) 

    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data\\tokens\\databasecred.json'

    file = PureWindowsPath(file)
    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data\\tokens\\databasecred.json'
```

Comment: Is your current working directory "D:\\programmieren\\python\\pixie\\pixie\\"? Because it is looking for the "data\\tokens\\databasecred.json" in the current working directory.

Comment: ................. I feel so dumb now. Target directory has one pixie less: D:\programmieren\python\pixie\data\tokens. God dammit.

Comment: you can use ``` os.path.dirname(data.__file__)``` to get the module path. so that you can work from any path not necessarily be in the  path "D:\\programmieren\\python\\pixie\\pixie\\"

Comment: but print(os.path.dirname(data.__file__)) returns D:\programmieren\python\pixie\pixie in my case (all modules are in pixie\pixie). How do i jump back one directory?

Comment: ```
from pathlib import Path
parent_path = Path(os.path.dirname(data.__file__)).parent
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot today. Esp. doublechecking path. :D